# Нужно отличать str и int в input() Python 3.7.2

Tags: python, python-3.x

Нужно чтобы input() получал только строку и ничего больше кроме строк.

```
While True:
  text = input()
  print(type(text)) 

>> 12345
>> <class 'str'>
>> hello
>> <class 'str'>
```

В этом и проблема, нужно разграничивать их, а как это сделать что-то не доходит. Знаю про `raw_input()` который был убран из python и переименован в `input()`, он вроде как получал только строку. И еще пытался писать всякие исключения по типа

```
try:
   text = str(input())
except ValueError:
   print('Enter only string, please')
```

Это не работает, можно ввести как строку так и числа. А нужно только строку :) Помогите!

Comment: Думаю, что вам просто необходимо выяснить, чем строка отличается от числа. 123 - число. "123" - строка. Все, что вводится в ``input()`` всегда строка, независимо от того, как выглядит.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Всё, что вводится в `input()` на выходе является строкой. Если вам не нужны числа, то можно проверить введенную строку функцией [isalpha()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalpha):

```
while True:
    text = input(" ")
    if text.isalpha():        
        break
    else:
        print('Enter only string, please')
```

Если во введенной строке разрешены пробелы и знаки препинания, то пригодится [isnumeric()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isnumeric):

```
if not text.isnumeric():
```